# Use of the verb "to ride" when referring to riding a motorcycle

Tags: word-usage

I'd like some clarifications about two points. The first is: is there any difference between the verb *bike* and *ride* in this example? Does the sentence sound natural in both cases?

> Yesterday I took my motorcycle and **rode/biked** to the park.

Second: do I always have to specify the vehicle (motorcycle in this case) in a sentence when I use the verb *ride* if it is known already by the context? (Considering all the various meanings the word *ride* has.)

For example, let's assume I've been talking a lot about the new motorcycle John has just bought and he is now in the garage where we know he keeps his motorcycle, is this sentence clear or ambiguous?

> Without thinking twice, John rode to town in search of his suspect.

Is it clear that he rode on his motorcycle rather than on a bus or taxi?

Comment: BTW you wouldn't say "ride on a taxi"; it would be "ride in a taxi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for usage outside North America, but as a motorcyclist in the U.S., I would say *biking* to mean *moyotcycling* is rare, and to *bike* meaning *ride a motorcycle* is even rarer.

Overall, motorcycling is not common in the U.S. It is very inexpensive to purchase, garage, and operate a car or truck compared to much of the world, so motorcycling has been relegated to recreational use, by a very small percentage of the population in most of the country. In contrast, bicycling has been a popular means of transportation for children for many decades, and is increasingly popular among adults. As such, to *bike*, to have a *bike*, to wear a *bike helmet*, to go *biking* to a *bike shop*, and so on will only be taken to refer to motorcycling where that context is firmly established, or if part of a compound which removes the ambiguity, like *dirtbiking* or a *sportbike*. Otherwise, most people will assume you are referring to human-powered bicycling.

One should also be careful with the word *biker*. While according to the dictionary this term could be used for any motorcyclist or bicyclist, in the U.S. it is strongly associated with the [outlaw biker subculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlaw_motorcycle_club) and its innumerable hordes of poseurs. *Motorcyclist* or *motorcycle rider* would be the neutral alternatives. I am a rider, not a biker.

To *ride* is the most common verb for operating a motorcycle, but again, the context must be established that you are not riding a bicycle, scooter, or horse. Your second example is fine if you have established that "John" is a motorcyclist; otherwise, it would be safer to specify the mode:

> Without thinking twice, John hopped on his Harley and rode to town in search of his suspect.

Comment: It should be pointed out that because of the word __motorbike__ (meaning motorcycle), the word _bike_ could in fact refer to a motorcycle or a bicycle, and if you said you hopped on your bike and rode to town, it could very well be a motorcycle.  So, you might want to say _motorbike_ in these situations, if there's any chance of ambiguity at all.  But nobody would say _biked_ to town, even if the motorcycle was a mere moped.